# How to check if template argument is std::variant?

Tags: c++

I want to write my own container `MyContainer`. Which implements an emplace method to construct objects in place.

```
template<typename T>
MyContainer<T>::emplace(Args ... args)
{
     // Some construction code ....
     *_cursor = T(args...);
     _cursor++;
     return *item;
}
```

Though, I want to always return the `Allocator` type. Though this becomes a problem if the the template argument `T` is of type `std::variant`. I would like to do an SFINAE that chooses the overload that fits one with `std::variant`.

```
template<typename T>
template<typename Allocator, typename ... Args>
Allocator&
MyContainer<T>::emplace(Args ... args)
{
     // Some construction code ....
     *_cursor = T(Allocator(args...)); // T is std::variant, Allocator is one variant of T.
     T* item = _cursor;
     _cursor++;
     return std::get<Allocator>(*item); // Here I want to return the correct variant
}
```

(I know the compiler could choose the overload based on if I provide the `Allocator` template arg or not. But I would like to create my container to have an emplace method for sub types of a particular type as well not just std::variant/union types. So I'm not look for those sort of answers).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a fairly basic case of using specialization to unravel a template type:

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T> struct is_variant : std::false_type {};

template<typename ...Args>
struct is_variant<std::variant<Args...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_variant_v=is_variant<T>::value;

int main()
{

    std::cout << is_variant_v<int> << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_variant_v<std::string> << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_variant_v<std::variant<int, double>> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That's your basic blueprint. In a template you can use this, perhaps in an `if constexpr` to execute the appropriate logic. Or use this as a building block for a more complicated specialization.

Comment: Works very well! Thanks for the answer! You saved me precious hours.

Comment: Could you, please throw in some explanation? Why is it `false_type` when there is only one parameter and `true_type` when many? You pass only one parameter every time in the example

Comment: This is called "template specialization". See the explanation of specializing templates in your C++ textbook.