# run std::visit on the variant and original type

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20, visitor-pattern

Have a strange case where sometimes a function takes a variant but other times it takes the member of the variant.

```
void branching_function(auto argument)
{
    using typer =  std::remove_reference<decltype(argument)>::type;
    using variant_type = std::variant<int,double>;
    // using variant_type = std::variant; <- doesn't work because missing <int, double> (here we could use a Concept over std::variant?)
    if constexpr(std::is_same<typer, variant_type>::value)
    {
        // std::variant action (do visit)
        std::visit([](auto argument_s){
            (void)argument_s;
        },argument);
    }
    else
    {
        //non std::variant action (don't do visit)
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xT1KcdK11

I can use a `if constexpr` + `std::is_same` to test if i'm on the variant case and get the expected behavior.

I'm struggling to figure out how to generalize the `std::is_same` test so that the condition applies to all std:: variants.

Is there some kind of "is visitable" concept in C++?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134598/1294207

Comment: I don't remember why I deleted my answer to this but it was presumably because of the much better C++20 answer that came in afterwards. Didn't @user17732522's answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Since C++20 it is straight-forward to test whether a call is well-formed:

```
void branching_function(auto argument)
{
    if constexpr(requires { std::visit([](auto){}, argument); })
    {
        std::visit([](auto argument_s){
            (void)argument_s;
        }, argument);
    }
    else
    {
        //non std::variant action (don't do visit)
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is that it will automatically work with any type for `argument` that `std::visit` would accept. This isn't only `std::variant`, but also classes publicly derived from `std::variant` (with some restrictions).